# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

help, cant access database. it can't direct me to my database cant use mysql_query for data retrieval.     i think it's in my newly created database that the system can't find? but the hosting site gave me no choice to rename my database

db_connect.php

```
<?php

include_once 'psl-config.php';   // As functions.php is not included
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

?>
```

where i call my user and database.
psl_config.php

```
<?php
define("HOST", "localhost");     // The host you want to connect to.
define("USER", "xxx");    // The database username. 
define("PASSWORD", "xxx");    // The database password. 
define("DATABASE", "xxx");    // The database name.

define("CAN_REGISTER", "any");
define("DEFAULT_ROLE", "member");

define("SECURE", FALSE);  

?>

$name = $_SESSION ['username'];
$result = mysql_query(" select score1 from members where username = '$name'");
```

username is stated correctly.
mysql query code line 14 is where the bug is.

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';

sec_session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
         header("Location: director.php");
    }



$name = $_SESSION ['username'];
$result = mysql_query(" select score1 from members where username = '$name'");


?>
```

i think it's in my newly created database that the system can't find? but the hosting site gave me no choice to rename my database

Comment: You're mixing `mysqli_` with `mysql_`. You're also sharing your credentials with us, which you should not do.

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). *They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation)*. See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which.

Comment: can you help me fix it? im just new in coding and i g=have no idea what's the diff.

Comment: i'm using wamp server only

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no prior research nor minimal understanding of the problem being solved

Comment: how can i use mysqli properly for data retrieval?

Comment: Start simply with a file that contains your credentials and connects to the database.

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: okay it kind of worked but this showed up.

Comment: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/jvsclres/public_html/tutorials.php on line 14

Comment: If you don't `exit;` after header location change, the script will go on...

Comment: @rayah you should really start by taking a couple of tutorials and working through code organization and the basic syntax. Everything here is fairly disjointed and would require major rework to make it operational at which point you'll have a hundred more questions.

Comment: @rayah Have you by chance consulted my answer below? It works.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
$result = mysql_query(" select...
```

it should be

```
$result = $mysqli->query("select...
```

and passing DB connection to the query.

using it as an [object oriented style](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) which is what your DB connection is.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
```

You are presently mixing MySQL APIs. Those two do not mix.

Use `mysqli_` exclusively. Do not include any `mysql_` functions anywhere in your code or included files. The same thing goes for required files.

---

I noticed you are using `sec_session_start()`. This is a function I have seen before. Make sure it is part of your included file, as I did not see any other mention of it in your posted code.

---

`DanFromGermany` made a good point about `header`

Place `exit;` after your header, otherwise your code will keep running:

```
header("Location: director.php");
  exit;
```

---

- Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Here is an example of using a [parametrized](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) method:

```
$name = $_SESSION ['username'];

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select score1 from members where username = ?");

$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);

    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }
```

---

Another example:

```
if($statement=$mysqli->prepare("select score1 from members where username = ?")){

 $name = $_SESSION ['username'];
 $statement-> bind_param("s", $name);

// Execute
 $statement-> execute();

// Bind results
 $statement-> bind_result($name);

// Fetch value
 while ( $statement-> fetch() ) {
 echo $name . "<br>";
 }

// Close statement
 $statement-> close();
 }

// Close entire connection
 $mysqli-> close();
```

Comment: Should probably be `$mysqli->query(...)`.

Comment: @tadman Good point, will edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix `mysqli` and `mysql`. I highly recommend using `mysqli` (with the i) as `mysql` is being deprecated. Additionally it's compatible with PostgreSQL which many of us are switching to since Oracle took over Sun Microsystems.